# Using SED or AWK to substitute values from 1 file to another

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Can somebody help me with a query that I'm trying to figure out? I am currently using 2 files. One file has the contents in a list with 2 columns with values below.

File_A.txt:

```
1 MSFT
2 YHOO
3 GOOG
4 APPL
5 SUN
```

FILE_B.txt:

```
### Client A ###
1
2
3

### Client B ###
2
3
4
5
```

++++

What I'm trying to achieve using any substitution method, for every occurrence of 1, change the value in File B to MFST. For every occurrence of 2 in File B, change that value to YHOO, 3 to GOOG, etc.

The only way I can do this currently is a manual and long process with the use of interactive sed. Is there any looping syntax I could use?

```
sed -i 's/\1\>/MSFT/g' FILE_B.txt
```

Thanks Very Much

Comment: Does every line inf FILE_B always have a match in FILE_A? Please [edit] your answer to state the answer to that question and if the answer is "no" then change your sample input to include such cases. Also add the expected output for your posted sample input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like that?

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR!=FNR{if($1 in a){$1=a[$1]};print}' File_A.txt FILE_B.txt
### Client A ###
MSFT
YHOO
GOOG

### Client B ###
YHOO
GOOG
APPL
SUN
```

If that works for you redirect the output to a tmp-file and then mv the tmp file over FILE_B.txt ... if `sponge` is installed you could just

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR!=FNR{if($1 in a){$1=a[$1]};print}' File_A.txt FILE_B.txt | sponge FILE_B.txt
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]} 1'` would be a bit more concise/idiomatic. Use `{print}` instead of `1` if you prefer of course.

Comment: @Chinaj2020 If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton :)

Answer (score 5):

a *really horrible* sed solution:

1. use sed to transform FILE_A into sed commands
2. apply that code to FILE_B

```bash
sed "$(sed 's/^/s!^/;s/ /$!/;s/$/!/' FILE_A.txt)" FILE_B.txt
```

Comment: Obfuscation at its best - totally worth an upvote ;)

Comment: I often look at sed code and wonder why people used to complain about perl looking like line noise.

Comment: Heh. Fair enough ... I mean, `sed` is turing-complete and all that, but I find it becomes unreadable VERY fast. :D

Comment: You're preaching to the choir

Comment: people, stop upvoting this!

Comment: `+1` for "really horrible" :-) Obviously it'd fail in various ways given various possible inputs, though. You could make it slightly less fragile by not using `!` as the generated delimiter as that can interact badly with shell history recall (I just get `-bash: !/': event not found` when I try it on MacOS) but that still leaves plenty of other ways it could fail.

Answer (score 1):

As a purist, I prefer solutions with a single `sed`, although some people could consider this unreadable, too:

```
sed '/^[0-9]* /{H;d;};G;s/^\([0-9]*\)\n.*\n\1 \([A-Z]*\).*/\2/;P;d' FILE_A.txt FILE_B.txt
```

I believe nobody desires an explanation of this.

Comment: When I try to run that on MacOS I just get `sed: -: No such file or directory`. "some people could consider this unreadable" - indeed :-).

Comment: I suspect both the use of `§` and the use of `\n` in the left hand side of the replacement operator are GNU extensions. I have to say, this is impressive @philippos, but calling it unreadable is an understatement! I have some basic sed knowledge, but this here feels like dark magic!

Comment: @terdon There are no GNU extensions involved. You can use any character instead of `§`; it's just used as a mark to separate the two files. And `\n` in the regular expression is pure POSIX. Only in the replacement (right side) it is a GNU extension. I'm fine with calling it easier to write than to read, but don't call it non-standard! (-;

Comment: @EdMorton This would mean the BSD implementation is non-standard? POSIX requires »*The standard input shall be used if […] a file operand is '-'*«

Comment: idk, just letting you know of the issue. Often with sed it's not that you can't do X (for any given X) in some other variant, it's that the syntax is slightly different and you need to add a `;` somewhere for example but idk if that's the case here or not, just thought it was worth mentioning so others don't waste time trying to run the command on MacOS sed.

Comment: FWIW though I just tried `sed 's/x/y/' -` with and without a pipe and got the same error message.

Comment: @EdMorton, hard to believe, but I'll check it. I always preach to stick to POSIX, because I love `sed` scripts running everywhere in every version, while it recently took me days to fix a build system after upgrading `awk`. But if MacOS `sed` violates the standard, it would be no better …

Comment: In my experience sed scripts beyond a simple `s/old/new/` usually involve some non-POSIX (usually GNU or BSD) extensions and slightly different syntax between the 2 even when they both support some specific functionality. I find it much easier to write POSIX-compliant awk scripts since you can do so much more so clearly/simply with awk than with sed.

Comment: You are right: The BSD version used in MacOS indeed violates the standard here, which is sad. It's annoying enough to deal with GNUisms, but still possible. But I never experienced other flavours to cause problems in such a simple straight-forward tool like `sed`. Btw, the portability issues of GNU `sed` mainly affect extensions in the `s` command (pattern and replacement), while most commands have no portability issues, so I can't agree with your theory (adding my bad experience with portability among even different versions of `gawk`). I updated the answer to solve the issue.